# Only output printable chars OpenWrt

Tags: linux, openwrt

perl is not a very good idea, because it's an OpenWrt router, so not enough space for it.
"cat -v" doesn't works, because it doesn't supports the "-v" option

Any ideas? :\

Here's a bad text: 
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zjMGHNq5

Between the "review" and the "kde" word, theres a non-printable char. For example i need to remove these kind of chars for texts :\
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'tr' can be used for this. Normally, you could do the following:

```
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < raw.php
```

This deletes any characters that aren't one of the ones listed. The \NNN notation represents the character in octal, this lets us get tab, newline, carriage return in addition to the other characters.

Busybox's `tr` currently has a bug when it comes to using octal character representation and ranges. Instead, this might cover you:

```
tr -cd '[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]' < raw.php
```

Comment: thanks! it works under bash/fedora, ok. but with openwrt...the shell is: "ash"/busybox.. it just gives an empty line, if i: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=J1kSv89F

Comment: @johnny8888 It looks like Busybox has a bug in their `tr` implementation. I added a workaround.

Comment: i tried: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Jnbxn0MX

Comment: I see the same bug on my router. But `tr -cd '\011\012 -~'` works.

Comment: WOW! tr -cd '\011\012 -~' really does work!! but how? what does it exactly do? it only allows exactly what chars? can you post you're answer in an "answer" so i could put a tick to it?? THANK YOU!

Comment: @johnny8888 - it's nearly the same, but for the range, it's using the ascii representation instead of the octal representation. Character `\40` is a ` ` (space) and `\176` is a `~`. So ` -~` Says space through ~.